# Mbunit - Gallio. Get name of the currently executing test

Tags: c#, mbunit, gallio

Is there a way to get the name of the currently executing test from ie the Setup method of a test fixture?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the TestContext:

```
    [Test]
    public void Pass()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Test name: {0}", TestContext.CurrentContext.Test.FullName);
    }
```